# Is it okay to ask a question as an 'answer' to a question?

Tags: discussion

There's an older question that had an answer accepted long ago, but the project in discussion is very similar to one I am currently working on. Is it okay to ask for additional information regarding the project that the question was about? The poster of the question probably had to overcome the particular problem I am having, but it is not discussed in the question they ask.

**For example:**

*Original Question:* How do you use a PMOS to kill power to an SD card from a PIC microcontroller?

*My Question:* How did you prevent current from leaking through the SD card's signal lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you should ask it as a separate question. In your *new* question, you can reference the previous post but please do not ask a question in a question.

On Stack Exchange, questions are very specific and each answer is a self-contained response to that question. If you start adding followup questions (i.e. question > answer > question > answer), that becomes a *discussion* and that is not what we do here.